# How to implement Intel MPI benchmarks for mpich2?

Tags: benchmarking, parallel-processing

Many people have recommended the use of Intel MPI benchmarks for mpich2, however the installation is not very simple. Could anyone provide steps for the installation and sample test case for it? Which other benchmarks can be used to test the performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone!

Actually we figured out that the problem was with the version(s) we were using. We were trying to run newer benchmark suits on older MPICH2 versions. Once an older Intel MPI Benchmark suite was used, it solved the problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Ohio MPI Benchmark - [OMB Benchmark Homepage](http://mvapich.cse.ohio-state.edu/benchmarks/)

> Ohio MicroBenchmark suite is a collection of independent MPI message passing performance microbenchmarks.  It includes traditional benchmarks and performance measures such as latency, bandwidth and host overhead and can be used for both traditional and GPU-enhanced nodes.

(from http://mvapich.cse.ohio-state.edu/benchmarks/)